# Getting a 'botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed' error when sending SMS on python

Tags: python, sms, boto3, amazon-sns

I'm working on a code that sends text messages from an ATM when they go over £200, however, when i run the code i get the error

> botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
>   Unknown parameter in input: "PhoneNumber", must be one of: TopicArn, TargetArn, Message, Subject, MessageStructure, MessageAttributes

my code is:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('sns','eu-west-1')
client.publish(PhoneNumber='+44XXXXXXXXXX', Message= 'Hello')
```

Where the X's reference a phone number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have examined your Python code snippet and I can confirm to the best of my ability there's nothing wrong with your code nor your code structure.

From the error, the issue is more related to the boto3 version i.e you are most likely using an older version of boto3 hence the old version is not able to pick-up the required parameter ["PhoneNumber"](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.publish)

Resolution Steps:

***1. Check the current version of boto3 :***

```
pip show boto3
```

or

```
>>> import boto3
>>> boto3.__version__
```

If the output is anything less than the current version (1.11.9) then proceed to upgrade your boto3 version as shown below.

***2. Upgrade your boto3:***

```
pip install botocore --upgrade
pip install boto3 --upgrade
```

Note: You'll need to log out for the changes to take effect

Hope this helps!

Comment: Glad to hear it's working. Would you kindly accept my answer to assist other users

Answer (score 0):

Running this locally with my credentials and phone number, a message sends with no issues -

```
import boto3

sns = boto3.client('sns', region_name='eu-west-1',
                   aws_access_key_id='xxxx',
                   aws_secret_access_key='xxxxx',
                   aws_session_token='xxxxx')
sns.publish(PhoneNumber='+44xxxxxxxxxx', Message= 'Hello')
```